# How to quote a variable inside wget command

Tags: github, header, wget, private-repository

The command runs well below:

```
wget --header 'Authorization: token GIT_PERSONAL_ACESS_TOKEN' https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../.../main/repo/packages/.../file.txt -P /opt/tomcat`
```

[image]

but I'm trying to extract the token, and run a shell script as below:

```
read -p "pls input the token:  " token
echo "print out my token: ${token}"
header="Authorization: token ${token}"
header=\'$header\'
echo "print out my header: ${header}"
wget --header "${header}" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../.../main/repo/packages/.../file.txt  -P /opt/tomcat
```

and I gain the 404 Not Found Respond:
[image]

wget version: 1.14

Does anyone have a clue to solve this problem~?

Answer (score 0):

finally figure out the reason by wget -d:
delete the apostrophe around the header and it works fine for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATBwj.png)

```
read -p "Input the token: " token
wget -d --header "Authorization: token ${token}" https://raw.githubusercontent.com/.../.../main/repo/packages/.../file.txt  -P /opt/tomcat
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXczq.png)